# QuickFIX/n Conditionally Required Field Missing (494)

Tags: c#, quickfixn

I am new to QuickFIX/n, I sent a MarketDataRequest but got a BussinessMessageReject with Tag 58 "**Conditionally Required Field Missing (494)**" which is Designation.

Anyone know how to set 494?

My TransportDataDictionary is FIXT1.1 and AppDataDictionary is FIX5.0

Here is my C# code:

```
 protected override QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest CreateMessage()
    {
        var message = new QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest();
        message.Set(new MDReqID("0"));
        message.Set(new SubscriptionRequestType('0'));
        message.Set(new MarketDepth(1));
        message.Set( new NoMDEntryTypes(1));
        message.Set(new NoRelatedSym(1));

        var noRelatedSymGroup = new QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
        noRelatedSymGroup.Set(new Symbol("123"));
        message.AddGroup(noRelatedSymGroup);

        var noMDEntryTypesGroup = new QuickFix.FIX50.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
        noMDEntryTypesGroup.Set(new MDEntryType('0'));            
        message.AddGroup(noMDEntryTypesGroup);            
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag is called [`Designation`](http://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/5.0.SP2/tagNum_494.html) by name (.NET class definition [here](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/blob/4c03a603f801a4e6d69a35120df0d14ba167ead2/QuickFIXn/Fields/Fields.cs#L8705-8715)). However it's not part of the FIX specification for this message type.

If it's really required by your couterparty, add it to the data dictionary (FIX50.xml) for the specific message type, and specify the altered data dictionary in [configuration](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html). Look for the `AppDataDictionary` setting.

Then Set the field as you would any other field.